# prove Walsh functions form a closed orthonormal system

Tags: linear-algebra

I got the following question at my homework:[image: The question]

I got stuck in  (2). I saw proof for that is orthonormal, but I don't know how to proof close system. I don't know even for which function those  Walsh function are basis of, does it a basis of all constants? if yes why?
if it is, can I use the same method of proving Haar system is close or not?

the proof of orthonormal: [image]

Comment: 2 questions: what is a "closed orthonormal system" anyway? (According to your book.)  And what is $L_{\mbox{pc}}^2[0,1]$?